# Is there a more efficient way to edit actions alread used in NLA?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

When not happy with the results in an animation the action can be edited again (<kbd>Tab</kbd> in NLA-editor). After that the action is displayed with a snowflake indicating that it needs to be freezed again.

After editing

[image]

After adding the updated action (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> Add Action Strip)  shown as Walk.001

[image]

Do I really need to replace all occurences of the edited action in the NLA-editor or is there a another way to apply changes (in place) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The snowflake button is only displayed for actions *not added as an NLA strip*, or *newly created ones*.

For actions already contained in a strip, it's much easier to select the strip and <kbd>Tab</kbd> to tweak it. After that, just <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to exit strip-tweaking mode. There's no need to replace existing strips: the action's change will be reflected immediately in all strips containing it.

[image: 1a]

At worst, you will have to **Sync Action Length** <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> on each strips and rearrange them if their action's duration is changed. Replacing action strips is almost never necessary.